# Is F : [0, 1] → [0, 1] same as F: R → R

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This might sound like a stupid question but is  F : [0, 1] → [0, 1] same as F: $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: $F: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ implies that $F$ is defined only on $[0,1]$ and it takes values only in $[0,1]$. You could say $F: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $[0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ but this gives less information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $F: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ means that $F$ takes in a real number between 0 and 1, inclusive, and gives you out a real number in the same range. $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ means that $F$ takes in any real number and gives you out a real number.

Answer (score 0):

No.  $F: [0,1]\to [0,1]$  indicates that $F$ is a function with domain $[0,1]$ and codomain $[0,1]$.  $F:R \to R$ indicates that $F$ is a function with domain $R$ and codomain $R$.  These are only the same if $R = [0,1]$.

(In light of the edited question $R = \mathbb{R}$, which is clearly not $[0,1]$, hence the answer to the question is an emphatic "No".)